# Is there any way to avoid sub queries?

Tags: sql-server, subquery, pivot, query-performance

I have following sample data in TEST table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
f1 varchar(50) NULL,
f2 varchar(50) NULL,
flag int NULL);

INSERT INTO [test]([f1],[f2],[flag]) VALUES('P','a',1);
INSERT INTO [test]([f1],[f2],[flag]) VALUES('P','b',0);
INSERT INTO [test]([f1],[f2],[flag]) VALUES('Q','c',1);
INSERT INTO [test]([f1],[f2],[flag]) VALUES('Q','d',0);
INSERT INTO [test]([f1],[f2],[flag]) VALUES('R','e',1);
INSERT INTO [test]([f1],[f2],[flag]) VALUES('S','f',0);
```

I want this result:

```
f1  f2whenFlagIs1   f2whenFlagIs0
P   a               b
Q   c               d
R   e               NULL
S   NULL            f
```

the following query has been written to have the same results:

```
SELECT isnull(test1.f1,test0.f1) f1, test1.f2 f2whenFlagIs1 , test0.f2 AS f2whenFlagIs0
FROM 
(select * from test where flag = 1) AS test1  full JOIN
(select * from test where flag = 0) AS test0 
ON test1.f1 = test0.f1
```

Is there any way to avoid sub queries?

Comment: +1 for sample data *and* desired results! Most question don't provide either, never mind both.

Comment: @abdkok: Do you have an PRIMARY KEY / UNIQUE constraint / unique  index on (`f1`,`flag`) columns ?

Comment: I removed the Oracle tag because this syntax is SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two ways, given the sample data, assuming that there can only be one value for every combination of `f1` + `flag`:

```
SELECT f1, 
  f2WhenFlagIs1 = MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN f2 END),
  f2WhenFlagIs0 = MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 0 THEN f2 END)
FROM dbo.TEST
GROUP BY f1;
```

Or

```
SELECT f1, f2WhenFlagIs1 = [1], f2WhenFlagIs0 = [0]
FROM dbo.TEST AS t
PIVOT (MAX(f2) FOR flag IN ([0],[1])) AS p;
```

If you can have more than one value for any given `f1`, `flag` pair, you'll need to better define your desired results.

Comment: Thanks for your results, Which one is efficient in large scale data?

Comment: @abdkok no idea, I've never done any performance tests. You could, though, especially since only you have access to your hardware, schema, indexes, data, and understand what you mean by "large scale data"...